# EOF is End of File in C but how can I write start of file?

Tags: c, file, io, stream

Just wondering is there any way I can check if a character is a first character in the whole file or input? Just like I can check if a character is EOF or not can I check if it is the start of file or not?

Comment: EOF isn't a character read from the file; it's a value returned by the library functions that *try* to read from the file, but couldn't (due to error or otherwise).  Regardless, no, there is no BOF. You *could* use `ftell` to examine the current file position, checking appropriately for potential failure of even that.

Comment: After you open a file with `fopen` you already are at the the beginning of a file. If you are asking if is there a special character to mark the beginning of the file, the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

EOF is a in-band-signalling value that is not read from the file, but generated by the system runtime environment (C standard library) to inform the program, that there's no more data to be read.

You can use `ftell` or `fgetpos` to retrieve the current read/write position of a file. If it tells you the position being 0, you know that you're at the start of file.

Comment: [`fgetpos()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetpos) does not give you the position, it gives you whether the call succeeded or not. The position is stored in the `fpos_t` argument, which is implementation-defined and might contain additional data like mbstate_t, i.e. you cannot read the position from it either (in a portable way).

Comment: @DevSolar: Well, yes, fgetpos gives you an implementation defined `fpos_t`, but implementation defined doesn't mean, that you must not access it. It's perfectly permissible to make use of implementation defined behavior as long as you take care to check the implementation at compile time.

Comment: Well, to be really exact the nature of `fpos_t` is *unspecified*, I.e. an implementation need not document or make accessible its innards in any way. And I wonder how you'd "check" the implementation at compile time (other than hoping that your compile fails if your assumptions don't hold, leaving the one trying the compilation scratching their head)...

Comment: @DevSolar: As far as I know every C implementation in existence will set a couple of preprocessor macros that will – very unambigously – identify the compiler being used. With that knowledge one can reliably test for well known implementation defined macros present in the implementation.

Comment: But `fpos_t` is the domain of the library implementation, not the compiler, so the compiler predefines will tell you jack squat about what's in that type. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: You will also get plenty of precocessor macros that unambiguously identify the C runtime library. If you don't believe me try this (works also with MSVC with different options, but I don't have that at hand right now): `for C in gcc clang ; do echo '#include <stdio.h>' | $C -dM -E - | egrep 'LIBC|GNUC|GCC|CLANG|MSC|llvm' ; done` – you'll have absolutely no problem identifying the compiler and the libc implementation at compile time.

Comment: ...all to defend an at best implementation-defined, non-portable solution when a portable one exists right there -- `frell`.

Answer (score 3):

You control as a programmer where you read from.

1. When you open the file (except when you append to the not empty existing file) you are at the first character of the file.
2. When you move the file pointer using `fseek` you tell the file system where to place the pointer. You can also use the `rewind`
3. You can ask the file system where you are in the file using `ftell`

EOF is not the last data of the file is just the information that you have tried to read past the end  of the file.

Comment: Same as with datenwolf's answer -- `fgetpos()` does **not** give you the position in the file, it gives you an oblique data structure that you can pass to `fsetpos()` to *restore* that position, no more.

Comment: *When you open the file you are at the first character of the file.* This statement is not so obvious if the file was opened for append mode `"a"` or `"a+"`

Comment: @chqrlie: Note that append mode only (quoting the standard here) "causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the fseek function." So an implementation would be at liberty to have the position at the beginning of the file right after opening, and repositioning only once a write operation is initiated... also, "opening
a binary file with append mode may initially position the file position indicator for the stream beyond the last data written, because of null character padding", so basically all bets are off. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: yes indeed, which is what I meant by *not so obvious*. If the file is open for appending, the position may or may not be at the beginning of the file. It is mostly irrelevant as reading from the file open for append (`"a"` or `"ab"`) is undefined anyway. But regarding update modes `"a+"` and `"ab+"`, the standard is bizarrely ambiguous as to whether reading from it just after opening it may occur at the beginning or the end of the file, and thus fail.

Comment: @chqrlie have in mind the question. OP is a beginner and requires a simple answer.

Comment: @P__J__: of course. The language-lawyering discussion belongs in the comments. I shall ask a separate question about the C Standard potential ambiguity.

Comment: @P__J__: Here is the answer: **7.21.3 Files** *[...] If a file can support positioning requests (such as a disk file, as opposed to a terminal), then a file position indicator associated with the stream is positioned at the start (character number zero) of the file, unless the file is opened with append mode in which case it is implementation-defined whether the file position indicator is initially positioned at the beginning or the end of the file. [...]* So your answer is correct.